# How to change the font family & style of textview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change the font style & family of the `UITextView` .Actually i will pick the font family from picker then change the font family of `UITextView`.Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: show your picker selection code

Comment: I have not written any code yet for font.I need code

Comment: write your code for creating picker and then make your data of fonts and on selection from picker apply selected font in textview then if you face any problem show your code.

Comment: I don't know what code to write for changing font family of the uitextview

Comment: this is worng bro, how do we know what the data contains in your picker table

Comment: See i just want to change the font family of text view by selecting an item from picker view

Answer (score 1):

in that assumption I submit my answer, customize yourself else if any queries ask here

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
 (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
   // here you can get index for selected Row
   [yourTextView setText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];

    [yourTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:18.0f]];
 yourTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 }
```

for picker [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_picker.htm)

Comment: can i change only the font family

Comment: @deepakkumar -- if you know that font family in already add your seif , surely works

Comment: I mean i don't want to change the font size so what to do in that case?@Anbu

Comment: @deepakkumar  - **[yourTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"addyourFontName" size:18.0f]];** // just change the font name , no need to change font size

Comment: ohh my god..it works like magic.Please tell what was that issue?

Comment: @deepakkumar -- how do I know bro, what you did , I just answered your question thats all I know bro,may be you are not mentioned properly in your font name if my answer is working fine give the upvote

Answer (score 0):

try this for showing name of family fontname in picker

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
UILabel* labelFontName = (UILabel*)view;
if (!labelFontName ){
    labelFontName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    labelFontName .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    labelFontName .TextAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    labelFontName .font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18];
}
NSString *stringForTitle= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",   [arrayOfYourPickerElements objectAtIndex:row]];// Fill the label text here
labelFontName .text = stringForTitle;
return labelFontName ;
}
```

after selecting fontName:

```
 yourTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:label size:17];
```